# Python: extracting an item from a list as a "number"

Tags: python, list, printing, element

Let's say I have a random list of integers

```
list = [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

I would like to add the first element of the list to the number 4 and get 9.

How could I do this?  list[:1] returns me another list and that is very troublesome.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [57]: seq = [5, 6, 7, 8]

In [58]: 4 + seq[0]
Out[58]: 9
```

By the way, never name a variable `list`, since it shadows the builtin of the same name. (Its a useful builtin, you may want it one day...)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't actually name my list as "list" (in my actual code) but I was too unimaginative to come up with another name here.  Will keep that in mind though.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is called *list slicing*. You can access a list element by using an *index*:

```
my_list = [5, 6, 7, 8]
print(4 + my_list[0])
```

**Notes:**

- Don't name your list `list`, because it will hide the built-in type `list` of Python. Give it another name like `my_list`, `L`, ...
- Remember that indices starts with `0`:

  `my_list[0] # first element`

  `my_list[1] # second element`

Comment: Haha, thanks.  This function was actually in my notes and I completely forgot about it.  I should probably go and get some rest.